# How do GC in HotSpot cooperate with each other

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

As we all know that in HotSpot there are seven GCs like Serial,CMS,G1 and so on.What I am confused is that all of them or only part of them is working at a time? How do them cooperate with each other to cover the task of garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

Below are possible combinations of GC algos in Java 8.

- `-XX:+UseSerialGC` - Serail Young (DefNew) + Serial Old Mark Sweep Compact
- `-XX:+UseParallelGC` - Parallel Young (PSYoungGen) + Serial Old  Mark Sweep Compact
- `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` - Parallel Young (PSYoungGen) + Parallel Old Mark Sweep Compact
- `-XX:+UseParNewGC` - Parallel Young (ParNew) + Serial Old Mark Sweep Compact
- `-XX:-UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` - Serial Young (DefNew) + Concurrent Mark Sweep (Old)
- `-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` - Parallel Young (ParNew) + Concurrent Mark Sweep (Old)
- `-XX:+UseG1GC` - G1

[Source of information](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html).

Parallel Scavenge and ParNew are very similar, but ParNew is compatible with CMS (concurrent mark sweep) and Parallel Scavenge with parallel Mark Sweep Compact old space collectors.

G1 solely covers both young and old collections.